# not able to bind results to column

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am not not able to bind results to column

this is apex class

```
public class SoqlEx2 {

    public List<Account> accs { set;get; }
    public String accName {set;get;}
    public String accIndustry {set;get;}

    public void search() {
        accs = [select Name ,Industry from Account ];
    }
}
```

this is my VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="SoqlEx2" >
<apex:form >


<apex:pageBlock title="Dynamic Sql">

<apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top">

<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}" rerender="table" /> 
<apex:commandButton value="Dynamic Query" action="{!dynamicsearch}" />

</apex:pageBlockButtons>

</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageblock id="table" title="Result" rendered="{!ISNULL(accs)}">

<apex:pageblockTable value="{!accs}" var="a">

<apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>

<apex:column value="{!a.Industry}"/>

</apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageblock>


</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Query is working right , I have tested it in console . but I am not getting why it is not binding result to pageblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following lines this will work,

```
<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}" reRender="table" />

<apex:pageblock id="table" title="Result" rendered="{!accs.size != 0}">
```

your rendered was returning false for ISNULL so change it to this `{!accs.size != 0}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put reRender attribute for 'search' commandButton and the value of reRender attribute will be the id of pageBlockTable where you want to display the results.

```
<apex:page controller="SoqlEx2" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock title="Result" >
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="accountTable">
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!accs}" var="a" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(accs))}">
                <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Industry}"/>
            </apex:pageblockTable>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top">
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}" reRender="accountTable" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Dynamic Query" action="{!dynamicsearch}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```